# Configuring WCF Forms Authentication

Tags: wcf, forms-authentication

In the implementation for my service I have:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
```

In my .config file I have:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

and:

```
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL = "false"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

and:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" />
```

In the "Login" method for my service, I have:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(request.UserName, false);
```

However, when I check:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

It is an empty string.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Forms authentication is used when you want the user to fill out a login form.

For a service it would be better to use a different authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ServiceContext.User.Identity instead.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are checking the Identity.Name on a subsequent request?

Do you have an  element in your web.config?

Also are you making sure to capture the cookie from the Login response and resending it on the subsequent requests?